# Heavy right tail distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, heavy-tailed

Does the standard normal distribution have a heavy right tail? How to prove it?
Does the standard log-normal distribution have a heavy right tail? How to prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: The best way to talk about heavy tails is to make comparisons between distribution, for example, that the Cauchy distribution has heavier tails than the Normal Distribution. A measure for calculating the heaviness of tails of a distribution is the Kurtosis. So, I would suggest calculating the Kurtosis for the distributions that you asked and compare their values.

Comment: First, you need a definition of "heaviness of tail."  There are infinitely many, so you need to pick one before doing the math.

Comment: For other threads about tails of lognormal distributions, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+tail.  @Fiodor Several people have argued here, rather strongly, that kurtosis is not a measure of the weight of a tail of a distribution.  You can find some of those discussions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tail+heavy+kurtosis.  Glen_b's account at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/172532/919 is thoughtful.